# Azure Service Bus connection string validation produces error 'The service collection cannot be modified because it is read-only'

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azureservicebus

I'm attempting to implement the Azure Service Bus connection string validation as demonstrated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71269205/9182405), but my subsequent attempt to add a service bus client as a singleton to the service collection is throwing an invalid operation exception that reads, 'The service collection cannot be modified because it is read-only.' Here's what my code currently looks like:

```cs
//  Validate the configuration:
await using var testClient = new ServiceBusClient(config.ServiceBusConnectionString);
await using var testSender = testClient.CreateSender(config.QueueName);

using var batch = await testSender.CreateMessageBatchAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

//  Add Azure Service Bus client:
services.AddSingleton(provider =>
{
    var client = new ServiceBusClient(
        config.ServiceBusConnectionString,
        new ServiceBusClientOptions
        {
            TransportType = ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpWebSockets
        });

    return client;
});
```

As in the post I'm referencing, my goal is simply to ensure that the configured connection string and queue name are well-formed and that the code is capable of establishing a connection. Is there a way to do this that circumvents the error I'm seeing?

**EDIT**

The stack trace, as requested:

```
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection.ThrowReadOnlyException()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection.System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceDescriptor>.Add(ServiceDescriptor item)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddSingleton(IServiceCollection services, Type serviceType, Func`2 implementationFactory)
   at Services.Audit.AuditServiceExtension.<AddAuditService>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Dumas.DED\Projects\Services.Audit\AuditServiceExtension.cs:line 36
   at Services.Audit.AuditServiceExtension.<AddAuditService>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Dumas.DED\Projects\Services.Audit\AuditServiceExtension.cs:line 63
   at Services.Audit.AuditServiceExtension.<AddAuditService>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Dumas.DED\Projects\Services.Audit\AuditServiceExtension.cs:line 63
```

Comment: What is you query?  The error indicates you are trying to perform a query that writes and you only have permission to perform Read Queries.

Comment: @jdweng There's no query to show, because this isn't a query operation - this is simply adding a client to the service bus collection during startup. The error appears to be due to the application being built before the singleton service can be added, but I don't understand how or why that would be happening.

Comment: Can you show us the full stack trace?

Comment: @JesseSquire Absolutely. Just added it.

Comment: Stack trace indicates that it is coming from the DI container.   It's orthogonal to the validation that you're doing for Service Bus.   Have you tested without the DI registration?

Comment: Then what is the value of "config.QueueName"

Comment: @JesseSquire By all accounts it should be. I don't know how the validation test would have any effect on the DI container, yet empirically it does. I have indeed tested without the DI registration, but it still causes literally every other downstream registration to fail, so it's kind of a non-starter.

Comment: @jdweng "config.QueueName" is a string that contains the name of the queue. Right now I have it set to "Audit", which is the name of the queue I set up in my Azure instance.

Comment: You need to modify the rules of the database.  Try troubleshooting with Powershell to see what rules need to be changed : https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/how-to-troubleshoot-exchange-online-transport-rules-using-the/ba-p/4000219

Comment: I'm unable to repro using the snippet above nor with the built-in "AddAzureServiceBus" DI registration extension.  If you're able to package a small, self-contained repro and open an issue in the Azure SDK repository, that would allow us to investigate further: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/new/choose

Comment: @JesseSquire - Roger that, sir. I'll get on it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the **`connectionstring`** you are using in your Code for Service Bus has **`correct Send, Listen Permissions`** assigned. I am using **Root Connection String** with all the permissions in my code:-

Use the **`Shared Access key`** of **`Service Bus Namespace`**. And **`not Service Bus queue`**.

[image]

My code with **`DI`** and making `ServiceBusClient` singleton:-

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        await RunAsync();
    }

    static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        // Setup dependency injection
        var serviceProvider = await ConfigureServicesAsync();

        // Get the ServiceBusClient from the service provider
        var serviceBusClient = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ServiceBusClient>();

        // Use the serviceBusClient as needed...

        // For example, creating a sender and sending a message
        await using var sender = serviceBusClient.CreateSender("myqueue");
        var message = new ServiceBusMessage("Hello, Service Bus!");
        await sender.SendMessageAsync(message);

        // The serviceBusClient doesn't need to be explicitly disposed, as it's managed by the DI container.

        // Ensure that the application does not exit immediately
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async Task<IServiceProvider> ConfigureServicesAsync()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        // Your configuration goes here (replace with actual connection string)
        var config = new { ServiceBusConnectionString = "Endpoint=sb://siliconsb67.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxx0TNmIcv+ASbDiecrE=" };

        // Validate the configuration:
        await using var testClient = new ServiceBusClient(config.ServiceBusConnectionString);
        await using var testSender = testClient.CreateSender("myqueue");

        // Add Azure Service Bus client:
        var serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient(
            config.ServiceBusConnectionString,
            new ServiceBusClientOptions
            {
                TransportType = ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpWebSockets
            });

        services.AddSingleton(serviceBusClient);

        // Build the service provider
        return services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Comment: How does this address the question of "why is my DI registration failing" that the OP is asking?

Comment: @JesseSquire I have given an alternative approach with the DI to achieve same scenario

Comment: @SiddheshDesai - I'm afraid it doesn't. The example you've provided doesn't address the fact that I'm attempting to validate the service bus configuration before the service provider is built.

Comment: @Dumas.Ded I see, In the above code, the validation of the Service Bus configuration occurs within the ConfigureServicesAsync method before constructing the service provider. This validation involves creating a test ServiceBusClient and a test sender.

Comment: @Dumas.DED // Validate the configuration:
await using var testClient = new ServiceBusClient(config.ServiceBusConnectionString);
await using var testSender = testClient.CreateSender("myqueue");
 In these lines, a test ServiceBusClient is created using the provided connection string, and a test sender is then created for a queue named "myqueue". If there is an issue with the provided connection string or if the queue doesn't exist, an exception will be thrown at this point, helping to identify configuration issues before building the service provider.

Comment: @Dumas.DED If the ServiceBusClient and ServiceBusSender can be successfully created in this validation step, it indicates that the configuration is correct. Only after this validation is successful, the actual ServiceBusClient for the application is created with the specified options:

var serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient(
    config.ServiceBusConnectionString,
    new ServiceBusClientOptions
    {
        TransportType = ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpWebSockets
    });

services.AddSingleton(serviceBusClient);

Comment: @Dumas.Ded That's how the code provided conducts validation before constructing the service provider, ensuring that the validated ServiceBusClient is utilized for the application. Any configuration issues would be identified during this validation step.